# Replacing a Gigabyte GA-Z68P-DS3 motherboard

Tags: motherboard

My PC started having issues a few years ago.

- It started turning off mid-way through gaming sessions
- It then had issues turning on, where all of the fans would start but the system  would shut down
- It now doesn't turn on at all

searching the internet has made me think my motherboard is the issue (Gigabyte GA-Z68P-DS3) and it looks like others have had similar issues with this motherboard too.

(My PSU is 700w 80+ certified but I don't think that was the issue)

I'm looking to just buy a brand new board, but as my one no longer exists anymore I'm struggling to understand what board I can purchase.

Do I just need to ensure it is a 1155 socket, compatible with my i5 2500k CPU and 1600 mhz DDR3 RAM? Is there a site that has the ability to suggest upgrades to an existing model you want to replace?

The Z68 chipset is no longer supported in products by the looks of it - can I just buy any board now as long as it supports the above 3 criteria?

Any help would be appreciated. I've been without my rig for 2 years and really want to get it sorted.

Thanks,

Evan

Comment: Pretty much any 1155 socket motherboard will meet your requirements.  Check the list of support CPUs before you purchase any motherboard though.  All socket  1155 socket motherboards only use DDR3 memory.